# How do I batch 'remote upload' files to Google Drive?

Tags: batch-file, google-drive-api

I have a list of .jpg URLs that I want to remote upload to Google Drive. I could do it one by one, but that would take hours. Is there a way to do it in bulk/batch? Any method should help.

I use a Windows 7 PC btw, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your files in your Google drive directory on your dektop. Your files will autonatically be uploaded.

`Copy "PATH:\*.jpg" "C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\google drive"`

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking for bulk "remote upload" to Google Drive. Currently, one can provide the direct url of a file hosted on a website to Google Drive, and the file gets remotely uploaded. This eliminates the need for the user to download the file, then upload it to Google Drive. In the web hosting parlance, I guess this is also known as transloading. I'm looking for a way to do this in 'bulk' with Google Drive.